# NSLog in submitted app

Tags: iphone, app-store, nslog, appstore-approval

I had the misfortune of submitting an app with an NSLog still active. It very rarely fires, but I would like to know what are the chances of my app being rejected because of that?

I am NOT asking how to supress NSLogs. I already know how to. It is just a stray NSLog which made it in by mistake.

Comment: So what happened? Did the app get rejected on grounds of having too many NSLogs, or was the accepted answer on the money?

Comment: @Yar: no, it went through with no problems at all. I later sent in a corrected version, but I doubt they noticed the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. I think I removed mine, but some aggressive GIT operations after-the-fact leave me in doubt :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there will be any problem. I've submitted several apps containing NSLog output which were accepted flawlessly.

Comment: Do a search here for Dlog debug, you should find a preprocessor directive that'll only print nslog in debug mode. Therefore, no worries when you submit app to store. Code will get stripped.

Comment: You are answering your own question which I did not ask,

Comment: Tob, sorry for the downgrade. I give you the check